Dynamically Get Project Solution Name in Nlog.Config file
We have a Blazor Template that we created for our team, to help new developers get up and running faster.  One of the pre-installed NuGet packages that we are including with this template is Nlog.
I was provided the nlog.config file below:
<nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<targets>
    <target name="logfile" fileName="C:/webcorp/NLogs/KitchenSink/${shortdate}/${logger}.txt" xsi:type="File">
        <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
            <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
            <attribute name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
            <attribute name="level" layout="${level}" />
            <attribute name="callsite" layout="${callsite}" />
            <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
        </layout>
    </target>
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="jsonFile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" readFrom="jsonFile" />
</rules>

In the 'target name' attribute, I want to replace 'KitchenSink' with the Project Solution name, dynamically.  Because, this file will be included in the template and (obviously), not all applications will be called KitchenSink.
My area of expertise is in CSS and GUI design.  And I am struggling to find a way to get the solution name dynamically.
I found This:
$(MSBuildProjectName).exe

However, when I replaced 'KitchenSink' with '$(MSBuildProjectName).exe' all that did was name the output folder '$(MSBuildProjectName).exe' and not the actual project solution name.
In Over My Head. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Did you actually create a VS template from this or you're just using it as a "template"? When you actually create a VS template, all instances of the project name will be replaced when someone creates a new project with that template.

Hi @Lex and thank you for that bit of clarification.  I did create an actual VS template.  And whaddya know!  You were ten thousand percent correct.  When I used the template to create a new project, it automatically updated the name, even in the url path for Nlog.  Couldn't have been easier!  Thank you
